# Add django-filter to class-based-view to allow user filter results on frontend

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Unfortunatelly Django doesn't have super-magic Drupal's analog for Views module https://www.drupal.org/project/views (by the way other cms also doesn't have it) so we all need write views in code and add content filters like everyone see in Django Admin by hand.

I need to add filters with dropdowns for Charfield and datepopup widget for DateTime field in my class-based-view, i found django-filter for this http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

But in docs no example how to setup it with CBW, only with function views.

views.py:

```
class VkwallpostListView(ListView):
    model = Vkwallpost
    context_object_name = "vk_list"

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["vk_list.html"]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        articles = Vkwallpost.objects.order_by("-date_created")[:5]
        videos = Fbpagepost.objects.order_by("-date_created")[:5]
        items = list(articles) + list(videos)
        items.sort(key=lambda i: i.date_created, reverse=True)
        return {"vk_fb_list": items[:5]}

    def get_queryset(self):
        wallposts = Vkwallpost.objects
        if 'all_posts' not in self.request.GET:
            pass
        elif 'all' in self.request.GET:
            pass
        else:
            success = False
            criteria = {}
            if 'sentiment' in self.request.GET:
                criteria['sentiment'] = self.request.GET['sentiment']                   
            print(criteria)
            wallposts = wallposts.filter(**criteria)

        return wallposts
```

And i want to easily add this filters:

```
import django_filters

class VkwallpostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Vkwallpost
        fields = ['sentiment', 'date_created']
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Django Form with [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) or [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield).

Its all that you need.